# Auto fill text-items after LOV selection for a text-item in an Oracle Form

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

Consider an Oracle Form having 3 text-items. First is a ***'PO Number'*** field which is user entered through an LOV called upon a button next to the text-item. Second is a ***'Supplier Code'*** text-item corresponding to the PO Number selected and third is a ***'Supplier Name'*** text-item corresponding to that supplier code.

Actual _PO_Number_ and _Supplier_Code_ exist in the same table in the Database but _Supplier_Name_ resides in different table. All i want is that when i select a *PO Number* from the LOV then remaining 2 fields should auto-populate accordingly.

What trigger should i use ? where should i use it and what other things should i consider ? Please help me as i am a noob at Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hava several posibilities with some consequences

1. Set _Supplier_Code_ and _Supplier_Name_ directly in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger on your buttob after user selects _PO_Number_

*Consequences* - when user presses standard KEY-LISTVAL, the code will not run, *Supplier**_ items remain empty

2. Write WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM on _PO_Number_ like this

   ```
   declare
       cursor c is select _Supplier_Code_, _Supplier_Name_
           from suppliers_table
           where _PO_Number_ = :your_block._PO_Number_;
   begin
       open c;
       fetch c into :your_block._Supplier_Code_, :your_block._Supplier_Name_;
       close c;
   end;
   ```

*Consequences* - this code runs always, when _PO_Number_ item changes. If _Supplier_Code_ is a database item, it will probably change its status to UPDATE after querying records from database.

3. select _Supplier_Code_ and _Supplier_Name_ items directly in LOV. Write your select as join of both tables. Set all three items as return items. If you don't want to show _Supplier_Code_ and _Supplier_Name_ to the user in LOV, simply set their width to 0

I preferre solution 3.

Comment: I tried a piece of code over the LOV button before your answer showed up  in my inbox. However, t was a tremendous help as your _**Solution 3**_ somewhat confirms what i did was correct. I attached a _**When-Button-Pressed_** trigger on a button for the _**PO_Number_** text-item.



Then i wrote a piece which calls the LOV when the button is pressed and trigger is fired. Beneath the _**show_LOV(LOV_name)_** block, i wrote a piece which selects and feeds the data into the corresponding _**'Supplier_Code'_** and _**'Supplier_Name'_**.

Comment: Now, when i run the form, all i ned to do is select a _**PO_Number_** from the LOV and other fields are populated automatically (fpor n selection through LOV).


P.S. - _**All the records for now are single records as these reside in header block._** and yes, you were a great help!

Comment: further, i am facing a problem when i am trying to create a detail block and populate the detail items. For example, there is a column named _**'ITEM_NAME'**_ which i need to be populated once i select the _**PO_Number**_ from the LOV. I created the detail block for _**Item_Name**_ and tried to establish a relationship between the master (header) and the detail block.

Everything goes fine when until and unless i compile the form. It throws an error saying - _**'FRM-30416: Relation's master block is a control block.'**_

Any remedies for the disease?

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, you can specify which table is 'suplier_code' refering to, when you create LOV, in the step where you write your sql code to select necessary parameters, after that select the needed rows to the 'look up return item' field